# Como cortar uma string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

**Exemplo:**

```
nome = "Josénildo da Silva Ramos do Carmo";
```

Cortar para ter até X caracteres, ficando assim:

```
nome = "Josénildo da Silva ";
```

No caso cortei para 20 caracteres.

Como faço isso em C#? Só sei em C (que é vetor). Em C# não consegui achar como.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É bem simples:

```
nome = nome.Substring(0, 20);
```

Neste caso está pegando 20 caracteres à partir do caractere na posição 0.

[Documentação do método](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_). À partir daí você pode ver na documentação todos os métodos que o tipo [`String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) permite. É bom dar uma decorada em tudo para saber o que já existe pronto.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GS6nQI). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2sQtND). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/BasicSubstring.cs).

Comment: Obrigado á ambos, não poderia imaginar que era tão simples assim rsrs (acostuma com C que é um terror kk). Você respondeu um pouco mais rápido que o @Caique C. (segundo o site aqui) então está como resposta certa.

Comment: É, C não tem o tipo `string` então tem que fazer tudo na mão, em C# boa parte das operações estão prontas no tipo.

Answer (score 7):

Utilize o método `Substring`.

```
var nome = "Josénildo da Silva Ramos do Carmo";
var novoNome = nome.Substring(0, 20);
```

O primeiro parâmetro indica o index inicial e o segundo é a contagem de caracteres que deve ser cortada, ou seja, o método acima vai pegar da posição 0 até 20 da string.